# Place an icon at the right of a label with CSS

Tags: html, css, icons, label

```css
#accordion input {
 display: none;
}
#accordion label {
 background: #88C2E6;
    color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: .125em;
 padding: .25em 1em;
 z-index: 20;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#accordion label:hover {
 opacity: 0.6;
}

#accordion label:after{
    content:url(http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/48/1480523700-arrow-dl.png);
    background-position: right;
}

#accordion input:checked + label {
 background: #88C2E6;
 color: white;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
#accordion article {
 background: white;
 height:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:10;
}
#accordion article p {
 padding: 1em;
}
#accordion input:checked article {
}
#accordion input:checked ~ article {
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: .125em;
    border-left: solid 1px #88C2E6;
    border-right: solid 1px #88C2E6;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" />
        <label for="check-1">Some label</label>
        <article>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </article>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have an accordion which consists of an input with a label and an article, when I click the label, the article expands or retracts. I'd like to add an icon at the right end of the label.

I tried using :after, like this :

```
#accordion label:after{
content:url(/img.png);
}
```

But then, the icon is placed right after the text, like this

> Text ICON

And I'd like it to be placed at the right, like this

> Text----------------------------------------------------------------------ICON

When I use the property background-position, it remains at the same place.

How should I do this ?

Comment: Inline elements (like SPAN, LABEL, etc.) are displayed so that their height and width are calculated by the browser based on their content. If you want to control height and width you have to change those elements' blocks.  label style changed to {display:block;width:100% }

Comment: Snippet added !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you could go with is setting `#accordion label`'s position to relative and the `:after` pseudo element to `absolute`. Then assign it with a `right` value of `0` (or whatever value you want).

```css
#accordion input {
 display: none;
}
#accordion label {
 background: #88C2E6;
    color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
    position: relative;
 margin-bottom: .125em;
 padding: .25em 1em;
 z-index: 20;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#accordion label:hover {
 opacity: 0.6;
}

#accordion label:after{
    content:url(http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/48/1480523700-arrow-dl.png);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

#accordion input:checked + label {
 background: #88C2E6;
 color: white;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
#accordion article {
 background: white;
 height:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:10;
}
#accordion article p {
 padding: 1em;
}
#accordion input:checked article {
}
#accordion input:checked ~ article {
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: .125em;
    border-left: solid 1px #88C2E6;
    border-right: solid 1px #88C2E6;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" />
        <label for="check-1">Some label</label>
        <article>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </article>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `position: absolute;` on your icon :

```css
#accordion input {
 display: none;
}
#accordion label {
 background: #88C2E6;
    color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: .125em;
 padding: .25em 1em;
 z-index: 20;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
#accordion label:hover {
 opacity: 0.6;
}

#accordion label:after{
    content:url(http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/48/1480523700-arrow-dl.png);
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
}

#accordion input:checked + label {
 background: #88C2E6;
 color: white;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
#accordion article {
 background: white;
 height:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:10;
}
#accordion article p {
 padding: 1em;
}
#accordion input:checked article {
}
#accordion input:checked ~ article {
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: .125em;
    border-left: solid 1px #88C2E6;
    border-right: solid 1px #88C2E6;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" />
        <label for="check-1">Some label</label>
        <article>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </article>
    </div>
  </div>
```